# iTunes connect adding glossy effect by default

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, icons, app-store-connect

I am submitting app to app store. In this process i have uploaded 1024 x 1024 pixel large app icon with glossy effect in itunes connect.

Even though my app icon has glossy effect, itunes connect is also adding glossy to it. Because of this we can see the glossy curve twice for my app icon in "iTunes connect".

How to say not to apply glossy to my app icon in itunes connect.

Thanks
Jithendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes connect / the App Store will show the glossy effect like you set it in your target settings in Xcode, once your app is uploaded. So you would have to tick the "prerendered icon" option next to your icons in your targets settings to avoid that Apple will add a glossy effect. 
As far as I know there's no other way. Of course you'll have to use the same image style (non-)glossy for both, the app icon in your app as well as for the large icon image you upload to iTunes connect.

Comment: I think iTunes connect will not have any interaction with code base. I am setting "Icon already includes gloss effects" to Yes in xcode plist file. Even then in iTunes connect is showing double glossy effect.

Comment: Believe me, it will upadate the iTunes connect image before the app goes into the App Store.

Comment: You're welcome :-) If you face any further issues, just leave a comment here :-)

Comment: @d4Rk ITC also added the gloss to my icon (only in the app store), now I made an update and in this update I set "Icon already includes gloss effect" to YES, will this remove the gloss in the store?

Answer (score 0):

when you submit  application on iTunes connect, after some time(before ready for sale)  apple  remove the glossy effect from the app store.Don.t worry

Comment: I have added my app details and icon in iTunes connect. Here in iTunes connect after sometime second glossy effect added to my icon. You mean after submitting app from xcode , app store will remove glossy effect and keeps only one glossy effect?